# Slice Twig path

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to delete the first occurrence of '/' in my twig path. I need it to show image in my pdf. I don't know how to deal with it and need help from someone smarter.

```
<p>{% path(project.mainImage), 'reference' %}</p>
```

Gives me:

> /upload/media/img/a6ab300301dd8e5de89bac068a16aaa9e90b2a1b.jpeg

I need:

> upload/media/img/a6ab300301dd8e5de89bac068a16aaa9e90b2a1b.jpeg

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not write a custom Twig function, or inject the proper, needed path into your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I am just stupid. 
Here is the answer:

```
{% set rendered %}{% path project.mainImage, 'reference' %}{% endset %}
<img src="{{ rendered|replace({'/upload':'upload'}) }}">
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: This code assumes that the URL always starts with '/upload' - would not work if anything other than that

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `slice` Twig filter, like this:

```
{% set rendered %}{% path project.mainImage, 'reference' %}{% endset %}
<img src="{{ rendered|slice(1) }}">
```

UPDATE:

And if you only want to do it on routes starting with `/`, you could do like this:

```
{% set rendered %}{% path project.mainImage, 'reference' %}{% endset %}

{% if rendered|slice(1) == '/' %}
  <img src="{{ rendered|slice(1) }}">
{% else %}
  <img src="{{ rendered }}">
{% endif %}
```